# PHP: read binary file containing UDP packets

Tags: php, udp

I have a program which listens to some udp packets being sent by other programs and saves it to a file. I need to make a parser in php to ready in the information which was captured from the other program which was listening.

I am attempting to use un_pack to get the UDP header, from which I could get the contents, but the ports and length headers do not match up with the current logs that the program is giving me so I think I am doing something wrong. I am kinda new to this kind of stuff, but bellow is what I have going on.

```
$i = 0;

$sourceport = unpack("S", $content[$i++].$content[$i++]);
$targetport = unpack("S", $content[$i++].$content[$i++]);
$length = unpack("S", $content[$i++].$content[$i++]);
$checksum = unpack("S", $content[$i++].$content[$i++]);
```

Oh and one more thing, I don't really know how to parse the data, will it just be in plain text or will I need to do something else with it?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how the program saves the UDP packets to the file. I suggest you look at the file, and compare it to the values you would expect to see in a UDP packet. If you can't understand the format of the file you're trying to read, you won't be able to write a program to parse it.